# MacBook Pro 2018 15" unable to push 4k60hz to external display (Hisense R7G5 - capable of 4k60hz)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi, 4k

Like so many others, I've plugged my 2018 MBP into my TV's HDMI 2.0 port (no DP or USB-C ports on my TV) using a USB-C hub, and it only will display as 4k30hz. My mouse movements are choppy and it's very unsettling lol.

I'm aware of the limitations that Apple has set upon the USB-C ports when it comes to 4k60hz (as well as the differences between the capabilities of the left and right ports), and have done quite a bit of research already.

- I can't even attempt to use SwitchResX or solutions like rebooting into Recovery Mode and disabling certain features because this MBP is a work computer and has safety protocols built-in that block me from trying them.
- I'd like to not drop almost $50 on a hack-y dongle like the [Accell USB-C to HDMI 2.0 Adapter](https://www.accellww.com/products/usb-c-to-hdmi-2-0-adapter), which might not even work based on the *very* mixed reviews I've read.
- I've read every answer and reply thread on [2018 MacBook Pro + LG 4k display = no 60hz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339812/2018-macbook-pro-lg-4k-display-no-60hz?newreg=3100095b32be4ea3a2e8bade12950ce8), and none of the solutions have worked (got my hopes up with the Option+Click "Scaled" menu in the Display System Preferences, but I *still* couldn't select 60hz, just 30 or 24).
- Scaling down to 1440 or even 1080 **still** doesn't give me a 60hz option.
- I tried two different USB-C to HDMI dongles and multiple HDMI 2.0 cables, no change.
- I also tried all 4 ports with those two dongles and HDMI cables.
- Only thing I haven't tried yet is a direct USB-C (Thunderbolt 3) to HDMI cable, an HDMI 2.1 cable, and a non-hub (USB-C to HDMI *only*... no supplemental USB-A or USB-C ports) dongle.

Anybody have any other tips to get this working, or at least new ones that I can try behind company security protocols?

Edit: I'm on MacOS Monterey v12.2.1. I'm including some screenshots of my Display Settings menu.
[image: No 60hz at 4k]

[image: No 60z at 1440p]

Answer (score 1):

Hilariously, I was wildly overthinking this.

I bought this [6' USB-C (Thunderbolt 3) to HDMI 2.0 cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075V5JK36) on Amazon, and it worked like a charm. 4k. 60hz. HDR. It won't support higher than 4k60hz, though, so if you have a monitor or TV that'll support higher, this solution won't work. (But I don't think a 2018 MBP can even go higher than 4k60hz, so this should be a non-issue.)

[image: 4k60hz achieved!]